# Unique records in related many to many sObjects

Tags: lookup, validation, validation-rule, master-detail

For example i have sObject named `User`, and it contain field `name`.

How check field `name` for unique, in input moment?

AND How do that in related many to many Objects?

For example i have three sObjects `Territory`, `Worker`, and `TerrWorker`- many to many table.

`Territory`->`TerrWorker` MD

`Worker`->`TerrWorker` Lookup

I want that every territory have list of unique workers.

How it is realize?

Comment: No worker can be in more than one territory? or no worker can appear twice in same territory?

Comment: No worker can appear twice in same territory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Duplicate Management

This could be performed using [Duplicate Management features of the platform](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm).

You would set up a Matching Rule on the `TerrWorker` object which would reference the combination of Territory and Worker and identify records where duplicates are found.

You would then define a Duplicate Rule to describe what action to take when a duplicate is identified by the Matching Rule.

### Uniqueness Constraint

This could also be performed by using a custom text field on `TerrWorker` which has been marked as `Unique` and concatenating the `Territory.Id` and the `Worker.Id` values and store them in this field. The unique constraint will prevent duplicate record entries of identical Territory + Worker from being created.